# Editing older revisions in RCS. Is there a way?

Tags: linux, rcs

Am working on a project where revision management is handled with RCS.  Let's say that rev 2.2 of a particular file is the rev most recently checked in.  I noticed that a while back the *wrong file* was checked in as rev 2.0.  I want to replace the wrong file with the right one.  But when I try to check the correct file in as rev. 2.0, I get the error `ci: RCS/the_code,v: revision 2.0 too low; must be higher than 2.2`

I've tried a few different flags, all with the same result.  Any idea how I can do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the bad revision and check in the correct file on a branch. That gives you all the correct versions in your history, but perhaps not in the order you want.

Or you could checkout each successive version and check each one into a new RCS directory, substituting the correct file as needed (basically rebuild the history from scratch). Use `-d` to restore the original date of each checkin, and -`w` to restore the original author name.

The way RCS stores its information (in a plain file called `RCS/filename,v`) is straightforward enough that you can just copy `filename,v` from one `RCS` directory to another.

(You're still using RCS? Really? Even the RCS sources are maintained in Git.)